# Python using requirements.txt

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

Im doing Google Ap Engine application,using Flask
when im add lib in requirements.txt my applcication not deploying
content requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.10.1
gunicorn==19.4.5
google-api-python-client==1.5.0
oauth2client==2.0.1
pandas==0.18.0
```

end its return error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Docker build aborted: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 143
```

if im remove "google-api-python-client",error disappear

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: wthoun google-api-python-client my app is not working

Comment: if i add google-api-python-client==1.5.0 in requirements.txt, my app is not publishing

Comment: Is requirements.txt correct? Is it in the right location, is it formatted right, etc? This error seems to be coming from Docker, not Google, and it looks like its having a problem with the requirements.txt. Be sure to also check the permissions on that file.

Comment: im write requerements text upper, it's correct?if im remove "google-api-python-client",error disappear

Comment: I assume are you able to install your `requirements.txt` in a local virtualenv?

Comment: Do you have a reason you need to use v1.5.0? I've pinned more than one library lately to use v1.4.2 due to incompatibilities with other aspects of the google cloud platform.